# Setting span labels with a loop

Tags: reactjs

I pulled data with request and now I'm trying to present each result on my site. I get an array with genres each time, so I need some ideas on how I could use loops in JSX in order to put those spans in result div that already has images, heading and stuff.

```
 setGenres = () => { 
    let data = this.props.data.genres;
    let labelsText = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        labelsText += <span className='genre'>data[i]</span>
    }

    return (labelsText);
  }

<div className='result-info'>
  <h4>{this.props.data.name}</h4>
  {this.setGenres()}
</div>
```

Back when I was using vanilla JS, I could use string and put it via innerHTML, but now I have no idea what to do. It just returns [Object object] on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` to iterate over the array and return another result. So it's possible to return a portion of JSX which will be rendered inside your `div`:

```
<div className='result-info'>
  <h4>{this.props.data.name}</h4>
  {this.props.data.genres.map((genre,idx)=>(
     <span key={idx} className='genre'>{genre}</span>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: fyi: has a missing closing parentheses

Answer (score 0):

JSX generates element classes for React to use. React allows rendering of various things, including arrays of React classes. In your scenario `setGenres` needs to change to the following.

```
setGenres = () => {
  const data = this.props.data.genres;
  const spans = data.map(genre => (<span key={genre} className='genre'>{genre}</span>));

  return spans;
}
```

As noted by another user, I added the `key` prop as react will complain otherwise. It's best to set the key to something guaranteed to be unique, rather than just an index.

You can read more about array mapping here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

You can read more about lists in react here - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: This code will create a warning about missing keys.